# JUnit 5 Test - Unable to Observe Nested LiveData Value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, android-livedata, junit5

## Overview

**Expected** - Saving nested LiveData values in a local unit test, and then asserting their values.

**Observed** - Saving nested LiveData values in a ViewModel are observed successfully in production code, but fail in the local unit test. This is potentially due to the lack of threading in local unit tests vs. running on the Android environment.

## Code

- ViewModel contains `LOADING`, `CONTENT`, and `ERROR` (LCE) conditions for when a user selects content to open.
- The LiveData `NotifyItemChangedEffect` state is saved in order to update the view.
- `NotifyItemChangedEffect` is saved inside of the function to save content sent to the view. **Only** in the `CONTENT` condition, the item selected is sent to the view with a LiveData object saved, `ContentToPlay`.
- In production, this works with the view's UI updating during `LOADING`, `CONTENT`, and `ERROR`, while `ContentToPlay` is **only** returned in the successful `CONTENT` condition.

*ContentViewModel.kt*

```
    is ContentSelected -> {
        _feedViewState.value = _feedViewState.value?.copy(

                // LiveData value for ContentToPlay initiated here.
                contentToPlay = switchMap(getAudiocast(contentSelected)) { lce ->
                    liveData {
                        when (lce) {
                            is Loading ->
                                _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                                        notifyItemChanged = liveData {
                                            emit(Event(NotifyItemChangedEffect(...)))
                                        })
                            is Lce.Content -> {
                                _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                                        notifyItemChanged = liveData {
                                            emit(Event(NotifyItemChangedEffect(...)))
                                        })

                                // LiveData value for ContentToPlay saved here.
                                emit(Event(lce.packet))
                            }
                            is Error -> {
                                _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                                        notifyItemChanged = liveData {
                                            emit(Event(NotifyItemChangedEffect(...)))
                                        })
                                _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                                        snackBar = liveData {
                                            emit(Event(SnackBarEffect(...)))
                                        })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
        ...
    }
```

- **By design** - `ContentToPlay` is not returned in the `LOADING` and `ERROR` conditions.
- **Issue** - The nested LiveData values for `NotifyItemChangedEffect` are not saved in the unit test, which update the view in each LCE condition. This code is executed inside of the LiveData saved for `ContentToPlay`. This pattern is logged and working in production.

*PlayContentTests.kt*

```
    @ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)
    class PlayContentTests {
        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("FeedLoad")
        fun `Play Content`(test: PlayContentTest) = runBlocking {
            // ViewModel method included to initiate ContentSelected event.
            ...
            when (test.lceState) {
                LOADING ->
                    assertThat(contentViewModel.viewEffect.getOrAwaitValue().notifyItemChanged.getOrAwaitValue().peekEvent()).isEqualTo(
                            NotifyItemChangedEffect(...))
                CONTENT -> {
                    assertThat(contentViewModel.feedViewState.getOrAwaitValue().contentToPlay.getOrAwaitValue().peekEvent()).isEqualTo(
                            ContentToPlay(...))
                    assertThat(contentViewModel.viewEffect.getOrAwaitValue().notifyItemChanged.getOrAwaitValue().peekEvent()).isEqualTo(
                            NotifyItemChangedEffect(...))
                }
                ERROR -> {
                    assertThat(contentViewModel.feedViewState.getOrAwaitValue().contentToPlay.getOrAwaitValue().peekEvent()).isEqualTo(
                            ContentToPlay(...))
                    assertThat(contentViewModel.viewEffect.getOrAwaitValue().notifyItemChanged.getOrAwaitValue().peekEvent()).isEqualTo(
                            NotifyItemChangedEffect(...))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Saving LiveData in all (LCE) Loading, Content, Error conditions

Saving a `ContentToPlay` LiveData value or `null` in all LCE conditions of the ViewModel to ensure a value is returned synchronously for local unit testing.

**Note** - The downside of this strategy is it emits a `ContentToPlay` value unnecessarily to the view in production code which is not ideal, but does not appear to be a major issue.

*ContentViewModel.kt*

```
    _feedViewState.value = _feedViewState.value?.copy(contentToPlay =
    switchMap(getAudiocast(contentSelected)) { lce ->
        liveData {
            when (lce) {
                is Loading -> {
                    setContentLoadingStatus(contentSelected.content.id, View.VISIBLE)
                    _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                            notifyItemChanged = liveData {
                                emit(Event(NotifyItemChangedEffect(contentSelected.position)))
                            })
                    // Empty ContentToPlay saved.
                    emit(Event(null))
                }
                is Lce.Content -> {
                    setContentLoadingStatus(contentSelected.content.id, View.GONE)
                    _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                            notifyItemChanged = liveData {
                                emit(Event(NotifyItemChangedEffect(contentSelected.position)))
                            })
                    // ContentToPlay saved.
                    emit(Event(lce.packet))
                }
                is Error -> {
                    setContentLoadingStatus(contentSelected.content.id, View.GONE)
                    _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                            notifyItemChanged = liveData {
                                emit(Event(NotifyItemChangedEffect(contentSelected.position)))
                            })
                    if (lce.packet.filePath.equals(TTS_CHAR_LIMIT_ERROR))
                        _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                                snackBar = liveData {
                                    emit(Event(SnackBarEffect(TTS_CHAR_LIMIT_ERROR_MESSAGE)))
                                })
                    else _viewEffect.value = _viewEffect.value?.copy(
                            snackBar = liveData {
                                emit(Event(SnackBarEffect(CONTENT_PLAY_ERROR)))
                            })
                    // Empty ContentToPlay saved.
                    emit(Event(null))
                }
            }
        }
    })
```